# STM32F - Cube Program Ends suddenly

Tags: c++, c, debugging, stm32, stm32cubemx

I was trying to blink the led on my STM32F446RE Nucleo Board. The Onboard LED is on A port 5th PIN. Program gives me the following error and also doesnt include my driver (gpio_drive.c) file. Here are the errors.
fatal error: stm32f4xx_gpio_driver.c: No such file or directory

And when i delete that and debug without that directory i get the following error:

WWDG_IRQHandler() at startup_stm32f446retx.s:116 0x80002bc
Infinite_Loop:
b Infinite_Loop
.size Default_Handler, .-Default_Handler

Here is the main code:

```
#include "stm32f4xx_gpio_driver.h"

void delay(void){

    for(uint32_t i = 0; i < 5000; i++);


}


int main(void){



    GPIO_Handle_t GpioLed;

    GpioLed.pGPIOx = GPIOA;

    GpioLed.GPIO_PinConfig.GPIO_PinNumber = GPIO_PIN_NO_5;
    GpioLed.GPIO_PinConfig.GPIO_PinSpeed = GPIO_SPEED_FAST;
    GpioLed.GPIO_PinConfig.GPIO_PinMode = GPIO_MODE_OUT;
    GpioLed.GPIO_PinConfig.GPIO_PinOPType = GPIO_OP_TYPE_PP;
    GpioLed.GPIO_PinConfig.GPIO_PinPuPdControl =GPIO_NO_PUPD;

    GPIO_PeriClockControl(GPIOA,ENABLE);

    GPIO_Init(&GpioLed);

    while(1){


        GPIO_ToggleOutputPin(GPIOA,GPIO_PIN_NO_5);
        delay();

    }

    return 0;

}
```

Here is my gpio.h file

```
/*
 * stm32fxx_gpio_driver.h
 *
 *  Created on: 20 Tem 2020
 *      Author: hkn_d
 */

#ifndef INC_STM32F4XX_GPIO_DRIVER_H_
#define INC_STM32F4XX_GPIO_DRIVER_H_

#include "stm32f4xx.h"


/*
 *
 * @GPIO_PIN_NUMBERS
 * GPIO Possible Pin Numbers
 */
#define GPIO_PIN_NO_0       0
#define GPIO_PIN_NO_1       1
#define GPIO_PIN_NO_2       2
#define GPIO_PIN_NO_3       3
#define GPIO_PIN_NO_4       4
#define GPIO_PIN_NO_5       5
#define GPIO_PIN_NO_6       6
#define GPIO_PIN_NO_7       7
#define GPIO_PIN_NO_8       8
#define GPIO_PIN_NO_9       9
#define GPIO_PIN_NO_10      10
#define GPIO_PIN_NO_11      11
#define GPIO_PIN_NO_12      12
#define GPIO_PIN_NO_13      13
#define GPIO_PIN_NO_14      14
#define GPIO_PIN_NO_15      15


/*
 *
 * @GPIO_PIN_MODES
 *
 *
 *GPIO Possible Pin Modes*/
#define GPIO_MODE_IN        0
#define GPIO_MODE_OUT       1
#define GPIO_MODE_ALTFN     2
#define GPIO_MODE_ANALOG    3
#define GPIO_MODE_IT_FT     4
#define GPIO_MODE_IT_RT     5
#define GPIO_MODE_IT_RFT    6

/*
 * @GPIO_OP_TYPES
  GPIO Output Types, Push Pull - Open Drain
*/
#define GPIO_OP_TYPE_PP     0
#define GPIO_OP_TYPE_OD     1

/*
 * @GPIO_SPEEDS
   GPIO Possible Pin Output Speeds
 */

#define GPIO_SPEED_LOW      0
#define GPIO_SPEED_MEDIUM   1
#define GPIO_SPEED_FAST     2
#define GPIO_SPEED_HIGH     3

/*
 *
 * @GPIO_PUPD
 * GPIO Pin pull-up and pull-down configuration macros
 */
#define GPIO_NO_PUPD        0
#define GPIO_PU             1
#define GPIO_PD             2







typedef struct{
    uint8_t GPIO_PinNumber;             /*< Possible values from @GPIO_PIN_NUMBERS>*/
    uint8_t GPIO_PinMode;               /*< Possible values from @GPIO_PIN_MODES>*/
    uint8_t GPIO_PinSpeed;              /*< Possible values from @GPIO_SPEEDS>*/
    uint8_t GPIO_PinPuPdControl;        /*< Possible values from @GPIO_PUPD*/
    uint8_t GPIO_PinOPType;             /*< Possible values from @GPIO_OP_TYPES>*/
    uint8_t GPIO_AltFunMode;            /*< Possible values from @GPIO_PIN_NUMBERS>*/

}GPIO_PinConfig_t;

typedef struct {

    GPIO_RegDef_t *pGPIOx; //Base address of GPIO port
    GPIO_PinConfig_t GPIO_PinConfig;


}GPIO_Handle_t;

/*Init - Deinit*/
void GPIO_Init(GPIO_Handle_t *pGPIOHandle);
void GPIO_DeInit(GPIO_RegDef_t *pGPIOx);

/*Peripheral Clock Setup*/
void GPIO_PeriClockControl(GPIO_RegDef_t *pGPIOx, uint8_t EnorDis);

/*Data Read & Write*/
uint8_t GPIO_ReadFromInputPin(GPIO_RegDef_t *pGPIOx, uint8_t PinNumber);
uint16_t GPIO_ReadFromInputPort(GPIO_RegDef_t *pGPIOx);
void GPIO_WriteToOutputPin(GPIO_RegDef_t *pGPIOx, uint8_t PinNumber, uint8_t Value);
void GPIO_WriteToOutputPort(GPIO_RegDef_t *pGPIOx, uint8_t Value);
void GPIO_ToggleOutputPin(GPIO_RegDef_t *pGPIOx, uint8_t PinNumber);

/*IRQ Configuration and ISR handling*/
void GPIO_IRQConfig(uint8_t IRQNumber, uint8_t IRQPriority, uint8_t EnorDi);
void GPIO_IRQHandling(uint8_t PinNumber);









#endif /* INC_STM32F4XX_GPIO_DRIVER_H_ */
```

Here is my gpiao.c file that i can't include (possible its because of i can not include this file):

```
/*
 * stm32f4xx_gpio_driver.c
 *
 *  Created on: 20 Tem 2020
 *      Author: hkn_d
 */


#include "stm32f4xx_gpio_driver.h"
#include "stm32f4xx.h"

/*****************************************
 * @fn      GPIO_Inıt
 *
 * @brief   This function initialize the GPIO on address.
 *
 * @param   [*pGPIOHandle]  Pointer of GPIO Handle Address
 *
 * @return  none
 *
 * @Note    none
 *
 */

void GPIO_Init(GPIO_Handle_t *pGPIOHandle){
            uint32_t    temp;
        //Deciding whether it is interrupt signal or not
        if(pGPIOHandle->GPIO_PinConfig.GPIO_PinMode<=GPIO_MODE_ANALOG)
        {
            temp = (pGPIOHandle->GPIO_PinConfig.GPIO_PinMode << (2 *pGPIOHandle->GPIO_PinConfig.GPIO_PinNumber));
            pGPIOHandle->pGPIOx->MODER &= ~(0x3 <<pGPIOHandle->GPIO_PinConfig.GPIO_PinNumber);  //Clearing Bits
            pGPIOHandle->pGPIOx->MODER |= temp;
        }

        else{

        }

            temp = 0;

            temp = (pGPIOHandle->GPIO_PinConfig.GPIO_PinSpeed << (2 *pGPIOHandle->GPIO_PinConfig.GPIO_PinNumber));
            pGPIOHandle->pGPIOx->OSPEEDER &= ~(0x3 <<pGPIOHandle->GPIO_PinConfig.GPIO_PinNumber);  //Clearing Bits
            pGPIOHandle->pGPIOx->OSPEEDER |= temp; //initialize speed
            temp = 0;

            temp = (pGPIOHandle->GPIO_PinConfig.GPIO_PinPuPdControl << (2 *pGPIOHandle->GPIO_PinConfig.GPIO_PinNumber));
                    pGPIOHandle->pGPIOx->PUPDR &= ~(0x3 <<pGPIOHandle->GPIO_PinConfig.GPIO_PinNumber);  //Clearing Bits
                    pGPIOHandle->pGPIOx->PUPDR |= temp; //initialize pull up/push down


            temp = (pGPIOHandle->GPIO_PinConfig.GPIO_PinOPType << pGPIOHandle->GPIO_PinConfig.GPIO_PinNumber);
            pGPIOHandle->pGPIOx->OTYPER &= ~(0x1 <<pGPIOHandle->GPIO_PinConfig.GPIO_PinNumber);  //Clearing Bits
            pGPIOHandle->pGPIOx->OTYPER |= temp; //initialize output type (open drain, push pull)

                if(temp == (pGPIOHandle->GPIO_PinConfig.GPIO_PinMode == GPIO_MODE_ALTFN)){
                //Configure Alt. Functionality
                    uint32_t    tempa;
                    if(pGPIOHandle->GPIO_PinConfig.GPIO_PinNumber <= GPIO_PIN_NO_7){
                    tempa = (pGPIOHandle->GPIO_PinConfig.GPIO_AltFunMode << (4 *pGPIOHandle->GPIO_PinConfig.GPIO_PinNumber));
                    pGPIOHandle->pGPIOx->AFRL &= ~(((0xF)) <<pGPIOHandle->GPIO_PinConfig.GPIO_PinNumber);  //Clearing Bits
                    pGPIOHandle->pGPIOx->AFRL   |= tempa; //Alternate Function Low Registers
                    }
                    else{
                    tempa = 0;
                    tempa = (pGPIOHandle->GPIO_PinConfig.GPIO_AltFunMode << (4 *pGPIOHandle->GPIO_PinConfig.GPIO_PinNumber));
                    pGPIOHandle->pGPIOx->AFRH &= ~(0xF <<pGPIOHandle->GPIO_PinConfig.GPIO_PinNumber);  //Clearing Bits
                    pGPIOHandle->pGPIOx->AFRH   |= tempa; //Alternate Function High Registers
                    }
            }
                else{

                }




}


/*Interrupt part will be discussed later.
 *
 * @fn      GPIO_Deinit
 *
 * @brief   This function deinitializes the GPIO on address.
 *
 * @param[**pGPIOx] Pointer to GPIO Register Definitions
 *
 * @return  none
 *
 * @Note    none
 *
 */

void GPIO_DeInit(GPIO_RegDef_t *pGPIOx){
            if(pGPIOx == GPIOA)
            {
            GPIOA_REG_RESET();
            }
            else if(pGPIOx == GPIOC){
            GPIOC_REG_RESET();
            }
            else if(pGPIOx == GPIOD){
            GPIOD_REG_RESET();
            }
            else if(pGPIOx == GPIOE){
            GPIOE_REG_RESET();
            }
            else if(pGPIOx == GPIOF){
            GPIOF_REG_RESET();
            }
            else if(pGPIOx == GPIOG){
            GPIOG_REG_RESET();
            }
            else if(pGPIOx == GPIOH){
            GPIOH_REG_RESET();
            }
            else if(pGPIOx == GPIOB){
            GPIOB_REG_RESET();
            }
        }






/*****************************************
 * @fn      GPIO_PeriClockControl
 *
 * @brief   This function controls GPIO peripheral clock.
 *
 * @param1[**pGPIOx]    Pointer to GPIO Register Definitions
 *
 * @param2[EnorDis] ENABLE or DISABLE macros
 *
 * @return  none
 *
 * @Note    none
 *
 */

void GPIO_PeriClockControl(GPIO_RegDef_t *pGPIOx, uint8_t EnorDi){

        if(EnorDi == ENABLE){
            if(pGPIOx == GPIOA)
            {
            GPIOA_PCLOCK_EN();
            }
            else if(pGPIOx == GPIOC){
            GPIOC_PCLOCK_EN();
            }
            else if(pGPIOx == GPIOD){
            GPIOD_PCLOCK_EN();
            }
            else if(pGPIOx == GPIOE){
            GPIOE_PCLOCK_EN();
            }
            else if(pGPIOx == GPIOF){
            GPIOF_PCLOCK_EN();
            }
            else if(pGPIOx == GPIOG){
            GPIOG_PCLOCK_EN();
            }
            else if(pGPIOx == GPIOH){
            GPIOH_PCLOCK_EN();
            }
            else if(pGPIOx == GPIOB){
                        GPIOB_PCLOCK_EN();
                        }
        }
        else{
            if(pGPIOx == GPIOA)
            {
            GPIOA_PCLOCK_DI();
            }
            else if(pGPIOx == GPIOC){
            GPIOC_PCLOCK_DI();
            }
            else if(pGPIOx == GPIOD){
            GPIOD_PCLOCK_DI();
            }
            else if(pGPIOx == GPIOE){
            GPIOE_PCLOCK_DI();
            }
            else if(pGPIOx == GPIOF){
            GPIOF_PCLOCK_DI();
            }
            else if(pGPIOx == GPIOG){
            GPIOG_PCLOCK_DI();
            }
            else if(pGPIOx == GPIOH){
            GPIOH_PCLOCK_DI();
            }
            else if(pGPIOx == GPIOB){
            GPIOB_PCLOCK_DI();
            }

        }

}

/*****************************************
 * @fn      GPIO_ReadFromInputPin
 *
 * @brief   This function reads from the decided pin.
 *
 * @param1[*pGPIOx]     Pointer to GPIO Register Definitions
 *
 * @param2[PinNumber]   ENABLE or DISABLE macros
 *
 * @return  uint8_t
 *
 * @Note    none
 *
 */
uint8_t GPIO_ReadFromInputPin(GPIO_RegDef_t *pGPIOx, uint8_t PinNumber){
        uint8_t value;

        value = (uint8_t)   ((pGPIOx->IDR   >> PinNumber) & 0x00000001);

        return value;

}

/*****************************************
 * @fn      PIO_ReadFromInputPort
 *
 * @brief   This function reads from the decided port.
 *
 * @param1[*pGPIOx]     Pointer to GPIO Register Definitions
 *
 *
 * @return  uint16_t
 *
 * @Note    none
 *
 */
uint16_t GPIO_ReadFromInputPort(GPIO_RegDef_t *pGPIOx){

            uint16_t value;

            value = (uint16_t) pGPIOx->IDR;

            return value;


}
/*****************************************
 * @fn      GPIO_WriteToOutputPin
 *
 * @brief   This function writes to the decided output pin.
 *
 * @param1[*pGPIOx]     Pointer to GPIO Register Definitions
 *
 * @param2[PinNumber]   8 bit variable for Pin Number
 *
 * @param3[Value]       Value to be written
 *
 * @return  none
 *
 * @Note    none
 *
 */
void GPIO_WriteToOutputPin(GPIO_RegDef_t *pGPIOx, uint8_t PinNumber, uint8_t Value){

        if(Value == GPIO_PIN_SET){
            pGPIOx->ODR |= ( 1<<PinNumber);

        }
        else{
            pGPIOx->ODR &= ~( 1<<PinNumber);

        }


}

/*****************************************
 * @fn      GPIO_WriteToOutputPort
 *
 * @brief   This function writes to the decided output port.
 *
 * @param1[*pGPIOx]     Pointer to GPIO Register Definitions
 *
 * @param2[Value]       Value to be written
 *
 * @return  none
 *
 * @Note    none
 *
 */
void GPIO_WriteToOutputPort(GPIO_RegDef_t *pGPIOx, uint8_t Value){

            pGPIOx->ODR = Value;





}

/*****************************************
 * @fn      GPIO_ToggleOutputPin
 *
 * @brief   This function toggles the decided pin.
 *
 * @param1[*pGPIOx]     Pointer to GPIO Register Definitions
 *
 * @param2[PinNumber]   8 bit variable for Pin Number
 *
 * @return  none
 *
 * @Note    none
 *
 */
void GPIO_ToggleOutputPin(GPIO_RegDef_t *pGPIOx, uint8_t PinNumber){

        (pGPIOx->ODR) = (pGPIOx->ODR ^ ( 1 << PinNumber));

}
```

Comment: C files must not be included.

Comment: Okay how should i do that including order?

Comment: What does your posted program have to do with cubes or cubing?

Comment: Prefer using `switch` in `GPIO_DeInit`.  It would make the code more readable.

Comment: Looks like you have an unhandled exception. Quite possibly a hard fault.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews - One would assume he is using stm32cubemx

Comment: @RealtimeRik What does hard fault means?

Comment: @HakanONAY if you do not know what hard fault is you need to start from the micro documentation. You cant program it without knowing how it works.